# Converting irrational fractions to a set of four proper/improper fractions

Tags: c++, math

This is sample code of what I am trying to do. Of course this would take forever to process (410^8).

Edit:

The goal is to allow a real number input in the approximate range of 0.0*/1 and 100.*/1 e.g. .457473343788374/1, 8.5476457654/1 and arrive at the *best* possible approximation using *four* fractions all having integers between two specified constraints (e.g. 16 to 400).

The fractions represent gear teeth in a machine that needs precise timing and can *fit* in a given space. Think of the Antikythera mechanism.

The main goal is to not stop when a close approximation is found, but to find the best approximation *that can't be improved upon* even at the expense of efficiency.

Is there an algorithm(s) especially for this type of problem?

```
for(auto_t num_1 = 20; num_1 != 431; num_1++)
  {
    for(auto_t num_2 = 20; num_2 != 431; num_2++)
      {
        for(auto_t num_3 = 20; num_3 != 431; num_3++)
          {
            for(auto_t num_4 = 20; num_4 != 431; num_4++)
              {
                for(auto_t num_5 = 20; num_5 != 431; num_5++)
                  {
                    for(auto_t num_6 = 20; num_6 != 431; num_6++)
                      {
                        for(auto_t num_7 = 20; num_7 != 431; num_7++)
                          {
                            for(auto_t num_8 = 20; num_8 != 431; num_8++)
                              {

        nOutput = double(num_1*num_2*num_3*num_4)/(num_5*num_6*num_7*num_8);

                              }
                          }
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
      }
 }
```

I have written something that works fairly quickly and returns what looks like accurate results.

Located here (64-bit, Vista or newer): http://1drv.ms/1zgpQnB

Examples:

pi ~~ (323 * 379 * 413 * 388)/(235 * 283 * 229 * 410) How would I confirm that this is as accurate as possible using 20 to 430 range? Or not (I suspect not).

More:

pi ~~ (381 701 341 523)/(309 573 128 669) using 25 to 750 as the constraints.

cos(45d) ~~ (617 713 723 92)/(485 734 263 442)              ''

Comment: Without loss of generality, assume $n_1 \leq n_2 \leq n_3 \leq n_4$, and similarly for denominators.

Comment: So you want the best possible approximation as the *product* of four fractions?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. On these machines they always use four pairs of quick-change gears even though one, two or three pairs could have an equal numerator and denominator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This type of loop is very inefficient. You are checking 411^8 ~ 8x10^20 possibilities. As Ben Voigt commented, you can reduce this by about a factor of 4!^2 ~ 600 by choosing an unordered set of denominators and an unordered set of numerators, but that's still terrible (10^17).

One quick reduction is to make a sorted collection of numerators, and a sorted collection of denominators, and then loop through the denominators, checking only the numerators just above and just below pi times the denominator. If the number of numerators is n, this takes about n log n steps if you do it efficiently. That's only a few billion steps, mostly spent sorting the lists, so you could actually do this, and you can sort numbers in parallel so it would scale easily.

There are improvements on this using lattice reduction.

However, the whole idea of finding such an approximation by trial and error this way is horrible. There is an area of mathematics called Diophantine approximation which includes approximating irrational numbers by rationals. You can find good approximations rapidly using the theory of simple continued fractions, or the Farey sequence. Here is one fast method for finding a lot of decent rational approximations: Start with 3/1 < pi < 4/1. Add the numerators and denominators to get 7/2. Compare pi to the new fraction. It's lower, so we have 3/1 < pi < 7/2. Iterate. This will hit all of the convergents of the simple continued fraction of pi, such as 22/7, 355/113, and 5419351/1725033. There are easy ways to speed this up slightly in awkward cases like 3.011 where you repeatedly adjust one fraction and not the other.

If for some reason you are attached to the products of fractions (is this a contest problem?), then I think you would be better off finding all good rational approximations, then work on factoring those into fractions with numerators and denominators in the ranges you specify.

Comment: +1 for "... finding all good rational approximations, then work on factoring those into fractions with numerators and denominators in the ranges you specify." The best rational approximation you can factor as required is the winner.

Comment: Thank you, Douglas! Your information helped immensely.

Answer (score 0):

It can easily be done in about 208 million steps with the following algorithm:

1. Iterate the integers from 1 to 208 million.
2. For each integer compute the denominator that comes closes to the desired fraction with that number as a numerator.
3. For each such numerator/denominator pair that comes closer to the previous best such pair, see if the numerator and denominator can be factored as needed. If so, update the best pair.

Comment: David, You, Douglas and Ben have steered me in the right direction. Thanks. Could you clarify where the 208 million integer ceiling comes from?

Comment: It might be necessary to test more than one denominator per numerator, if the lowest-error one cannot be factored, the second-best one could still improve on the prior feasible solution.

Comment: I suspect it's also better to build a sieve of all reachable numbers rather than factoring afterward.  The key is to enumerate either numerators or denominators and calculate the other, not enumerate the full cartesian product.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: I disagree because the chance that one of the convergents or near-convergents is (410-)smooth is high, and it doesn't take long to test whether numbers are smooth.